# Haskell cannot infer instance error

Tags: haskell, instance

```
f2 x = a*b/(b^3 + 6*a)
    where 
    a = sqrt (2x-5)
    b = sin x
```

This example returns the following error: 
Cannot infer instance
Instance   : Num (a -> a)
Expression : f2

But this one works just fine:

```
f x = (a*sin b)/(b^3 - 6*a)
    where
    a = sqrt x
    b = 2*x + 3
```

Will be grateful for any hints on how to make it work.

Comment: Is this correct? `a = sqrt (2x-5)`

Comment: `2x` means "apply function `2` to argument `x`", which is not what you want -- you forgot the `*` sign.

Answer (score 1):

```
f2 x = a*b/(b^3 + 6*a)
    where 
    a = sqrt     (2x - 5)
    b = sin x --  ^^^
              --  2*x, not 2x. 2x is the same as 2(x).
```